# Benefits of a redirecting page after logging in

Tags: php

I see many sites (like ones using vbulletin) that have a...

> Thank you! You were succesfully logged in. **Click here to continue**

page.

Are there any benefits/advantages of doing such? What's the difference between that and not redirecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flow *with* the redirection site is the following (opener page here means the first page of your "logged in"-area):

```
login page --(login data)--> redirect page ----> opener page
```

as opposed to this flow without it:

```
login page --(login data)--> opener page
```

The difference appears, when the user is on the opener page and hits reload. In the first case just the page reloads and everything is (hopyfully) fine.

In the second case, however, the login data is sent again. This has two consequences:

1. Most browsers will display a "Do you really want to resend that data?" dialog to the user. Probably confusing the user; maybe even so much, that he leaves your site.
2. On the backend side another login process may be triggered. This can mess up some protection against multiple logins or your logging of user activity.

In general the first consequence is much more critical, as the second can be prevented by you as the page developer. So basically you save your users some time by not confronting them with a (unnecessary) dialog box and a happy user is a recurring user.

**edit after the comments**

@Christoph: The above pattern is called [PRG-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

@CodeCaster: Instead of a separate page, just send a [302-redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) in the response header directly after the login.

Comment: Perfect answer. Imagine you have a log to generate a report to show you who logged in where. If you don't redirect, and the user reloads, there's a good chance that he will appear twice in your log.

Comment: It's indeed probably to prevent the 'Resend POST data?' popup when clicking Back in the browser, but putting a page in between will only make that popup show when the Back button is clicked twice... Better just send a 302 redirection after a succesful login. It's a no-brainer page, really, that only slows down the experience. "Oh how nice, I am logged in, I totally did not expect that after entering my credentials".

Comment: But what I don't get is why they show the redirect page instead of sending a `HTTP 30X` redirect page that makes the browser automatically redirect the user to the new page without the need to follow a link. This works too (when the user refreshes the page after login it just loads the new page without sending the login data and without triggering the login process) and is more comfortable for the end user. See [Post/Redirect/Get in the Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós Some old/exotic clients may not support the 302-header and thus showing a separate page is kind of a fallback for this, as even if the (JavaScript?) redirect of the redirect page does not work, the user actually sees, that he has to go to the next page.

Comment: The 302 page may have some contents, like the page you are actually seeing in vbulletin, so it should not affect. If the user is using some common browser, his/her browser will see the `30X header` with the `Location:` one and will redirect automatically without showing the contents to the user. If the user is using NCSA Mosaic 0.7 or some other exotic browser which may not understand 30X redirects, then he/she will see the `Click here to continue` link

Answer (score 0):

This solution is the best in my mind when you don't want to use javascript to proceed to User login. 
You can use this but I prefer auto-redirect user after login.

The best for user interaction is in my mind Javascript login.
You don't redirect the user, don't reload the page and it's faster

Comment: But then the login cookie is accessible via JS which may allow an attacker to impersonate you using XSS attacks. See the http-only flag in cookies: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie